# procedure of statistical modeling of sample

Tags: modeling, sample

I never did the statistical modeling of sample. Usually i was engaged in common  statistical procedures(descriptive statistic, correlation, regression, factor analysis and so on). Now i decided find out how simulate any sample? for example, 
i need simulate sample of 200 people. Suppose, it's psychological research, i have any methodics and each of them has  certain parameters(scales).
imagine that each methodics has 5-10 scales and we have 5 methodics. Finally, we have to work with 25-50 parameters.
What i must know and must do to simulate my sample?
and how modeling procedure can be done using SPSS or statistical software?
For a start, suppose that 100 people of sample are men, and 100 people of sample are women,
and my hypothisis that mean values of each parameter are different between men and women (using Anova)
and correlation between parameters are different in men and women

Answer (score 0):

I found answer. there is menu in statistica 10. it's called [Distribution fitting](https://www.statsoft.com/Textbook/Distribution-Fitting). So it menu has many methods for simulations any sample.